# headless wordpress

Tags: plugins

Im a basic wordpress user for several years now. Im not a pro, using WP only for hobby/personal projects to help out others. I love wp's simplicity, structure and easy theme changes and its plugin structures. Wordpress is awesome for a beginner!

Recently my sites hosting company is increased 4x the shared hosting price from last year to this year, and i fed up looking for another paid hosting. I found netlify and started to move my hobby projects to static html. I have been searching actively on the net in the last 2 months looking for an easy to use solution for beginners/noncoders to manage a blog in static html.

The easiest so far what i have found is Publii, the only problem it doesnt have a portable solution.

I have seen under different topics all over the web (dev sites, forums, reddits, etc) there are tens of thousands of users like me, who doesnt want to code just manage a simple personal project, like a personal blog or wiki.

Can you develop a desktop standalone easy to use wordpress client (headless wordpress) automatically integrated to netlify/S3/bitbucket/github pages?

I know there is a solution called [netlify cms](https://www.netlifycms.org/), but its dashboard is way too simple and technical, and under WP there is WPStatic plugin (or 'deploy to netlify'), i tried many other solutions, and still miss the real wordpress experience. An integrated cross platform portable solution would make a lot of success for a lot of basic users out there. Something like [publii](https://getpublii.com/) just under Wordpress. Something like [Thingamablog](https://www.thingamablog.com/) running with wordpress dashboard.

After two months of trying install+configure+deploy hugo+netlify, Gatsby+netlify, headless wordpress+wpstatic, publish to netlify, etc. i still didnt found an easy to use solution (+easy to change themes) for beginners. The forums are full of comments like mine, if you look around abit, you will see there are many people out there who are struggling to find something similar.

"Wordpress for desktop" would be an ideal solution, if it would provide publishing possibilities to static site hostings. I don't want to be a coder, just want to change easily themes and publish a small blog using wordpress dashboard as local backend, and netlify static html as frontend. I tried "local by flywheel" and LAMP stack also but its all over complicated for a single task of WP management.

So, i guess im talking in the name of huge amount of beginners. Can you help us with a single easy to use netlify+s3+ portable WP desktop application?

thanks!

Comment: Hello! And welcome to Stack Exchange, as this is a Q&A site rather than a discussion forum, we need to be able to answer a specific question, can you state clearly what the question is? Your question is quite long and could be interpreted in several ways

Comment: Hello Tom,thanks for your answer. Im a basic WP user. Its good that you can interpret this questions in many way, so im looking forward to hear all your interpretations and answers. Thanks!